# Passing multiple tables from stored procedure performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-performance

If we pull multiple tables from stored procedure instead of procedure per table, how it will affect Sql Server's performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the database engine itself and the load on it, it makes little difference.

In terms of network IO, it is normally better to do one big query than several small ones, as each connection takes some time to setup.

In general - pull in all the data you need in one batch instead of several if performance of the database and application are important.

Comment: I especially like the exception logic "in general"

Comment: @xQbert - There are _always_ exceptions. And rule #1 of performance - measure before changing, measure after...

Comment: I'm in total agreement.  and when the measure after the change shows a negative result, put it back the way it was and rethink what you're doing.